# Why checkpoint is needed on an Amazon Kinesis stream when shutting down a shard?

Tags: amazon-kinesis

When splitting a shard into 2 child shards, the parent shard is shutdown. It is expecting that the record processor(KCL is being used here) would checkpoint when this happens as the following KCL source code shows:

```
try {
                recordProcessor.shutdown(recordProcessorCheckpointer, reason);
                String lastCheckpointValue = recordProcessorCheckpointer.getLastCheckpointValue();
                if (reason == ShutdownReason.TERMINATE) {
                    if ((lastCheckpointValue == null)
                            || (!lastCheckpointValue.equals(SentinelCheckpoint.SHARD_END.toString()))) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Application didn't checkpoint at end of shard "
                                + shardInfo.getShardId());
                    }
                }
```

The questions are:

- Is this checkpoint indispensable?
- What happens if the record processor does not checkpoint and absorbs the exception?

The reason I am asking is because in my use case I want to make sure that every record from the stream has been processed to s3, now if the shard is shutdown, there might be items which have not been flushed yet and therefore i want to make sure they would be resent to the new consumer/worker of the child-shard?

They wouldn't be resent if I checkpoint.

Any ideas?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Items don't move between shards. After re-sharding, new records are put into new shards, but old records are never transferred from the parent shard, and no more new records are added to the (now closed) parent shard. Data persists in the parent shard for its normal 24 hour lifespan even after it is closed. Your record processor would only be shutdown after it has reached the end of the data from the parent shard.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/kinesis-using-sdk-java-after-resharding.html

BTW, as you probably know the SDK API is difficult, and the client library isn't a whole lot better. Try the connector library, which is a much better API and includes an example of an S3 archiving application.

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-connectors

Comment: Thx. That is useful. One question though based on what you said, if i put 1000 records in a one shard stream. Then after 500 have been consumed, i split the stream into 2. Assuming i use the KCL (not reading with the native API), what is going to be the behavior of the KCL. Will it make sure i will have 3 RecordProcessors for a while until the 500 remaining are consumed, or will it just have 2 record processors for the child shards, and basically the 500 remaining are lost? Thx in advance.

Comment: Your consumption has *no effect whatsoever* on the disposition of the records. The shard is selected at input time. If you put 1000 records in one shard, then split, you will have 1000 records in the original shard and no records in the the child shards. It doesn't matter when you consume anything.

Comment: And to clarify, the library will spawn two more processors for the child shards, but they will do nothing until more records are added. All 1000 records will be processed by the original parent shard processor, because that's where those records exist.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear,true consumption has no effect, that is just an example of the potential data loss. I'll clarify more, when a shard is split, i am seeing clearly that the a shutdown method is called on my record processor. I interpret this shutdown as : "No more records will be sent to you". Question is: is it guaranteed that the KCL will call the shutdown method after it sent all the pending records to my processor, or will the shutdown be called immediately on split in which case i basically lost the remaining 500 records that were never consumed since my processor is being shutdown?

Comment: You are shut down when the end of the closed shard data is reached (when the shard iterator returns null), *not* when the shard is closed. You will not lose the records.